# How to remove "selected" outline when an image is clicked

Tags: html, css

On a clients website a blue outline appears around the images when clicked. Does anyone know how to remove them? (I am using chrome on Windows 8 by the way)

http://damien-harrow-photography.co.uk/index.php?/category/3

Answer (score 0):

It is not the image you see being selected but rather the a (link) tag  the image is contained in which is being selected.  so you cannot remove this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help (CSS):

```
a {outline: 0 !important;}
a:focus {outline: 0 !important;}
```

Hovewer, this outline is maybe a little aesthetic, but for some people with use problems, they can be really helpful. Additionally when You navigate through your site using tab, you know where You are. So the answer is You can remove them, but You should not.
Best regards! :)

Great resource: http://outlinenone.com/